# With Hilt, how do you access an injected dependency for anaylsis during a test?

Tags: android, testing, dagger-hilt

I would like to provide a ThreadSafeMemoryCache to Hilt during the test that it will use to inject the MudicRepository under test so I can inspect the ThreadSafeMemoryCache without exposing the cache via a getter during the test. This would be very easy if I was doing manual DI (I would have access to the constructed instance before injection into the MusicRepository), but I have no idea how to do that using Hilt.

I have this as a first try, but I cannot access the threadSafeMemoryCache in both the module and the test class.

```
@Inject
lateinit var threadSafeMemoryCache: ThreadSafeMemoryCache<List<MusicFile>>

@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [ThreadSafeMemoryCache::class]
)
abstract class ThreadSafeMemoryCacheModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideThreadSafeMemoryCache(): ThreadSafeMemoryCache<List<MusicFile>>{
        return threadSafeMemoryCache
    }

}
```

I want to intercept the cache injected into a repository so I can be sure the cache is being used by the repository.

This is the class that has the cache

```
@Singleton
class MusicRepository @Inject constructor() {

    @Inject
    internal lateinit var musicCache: ThreadSafeMemoryCache<List<MusicFile>>
...
```

and I have Hilt inject the repository under test in the test class.

```
@Inject
lateinit var musicRepository: MusicRepository
```

Answer (score 0):

This would cause issues if the Object to be injected had to be injected under a non-singleton scope (an edit or other answer would help), but I can bind an Object to the Hilt graph's singleton component with the following code, so that Hilt uses that Object whenever it injects it into a class.

```
@BindValue @JvmField
val threadSafeMemoryCache = ThreadSafeMemoryCache<List<MusicFile>>()
```

Comment: As a side note, the class being tested had a bad design, and a little refactoring made it easier to test and easier to use.